# PHP Regex, Only getting back partial Results

Tags: php, regex

**I have the following PHP regex:**

```
@<tr[\s\S]*?<a class="b1"[\s\S]*?<em[^>]*>([^<]*)[\s\S]*?stars_small_([0-9].[0-9])@
```

**Which I am using on this site:**

[Gamespy](http://xbox360.gamespy.com/index/reviews.html?ordering.attribute=game.lower_catalog_name&ordering.order=asc&constraint.return_all=is_true&constraint.catalog_letter.game=A&default.sort.attribute=game.lower_catalog_name&default.sort.order=asc)

**I get back this data:**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AC/DC Live: Rock Band Track Pack
            [1] => Ace Combat 6: Fires of Liberation
            [2] => All-Pro Football 2K8
            [3] => Alone in the Dark
            [4] => Armored Core 4
            [5] => Army of Two
            [6] => Army of Two: The 40th Day
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.5
            [1] => 2.5
            [2] => 3.5
            [3] => 3.5
            [4] => 2.5
            [5] => 3.5
            [6] => 3.5
        )
```

This is what I am looking for, however I don't seem to be getting back all of the data. I should get the following Titles with scores. But for some reason I am only getting some of them.

```
AC/DC Live: Rock Band Track Pack     
Ace Combat 6: Fires of Liberation    
Afro Samurai         
Alan Wake    
Aliens vs. Predator  
All-Pro Football 2K8    
Alone in the Dark   
Amped 3     
Armored Core 4  
Army of Two 
Army of Two: The 40th Day   
Assassin's Creed     
Assassin's Creed II  
Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood    
Avatar: The Game
```

**I have tested my regex here:**

http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

**Using this HTML:**

http://justpaste.it/20u5

Any help explaining why I am only getting back some of the results would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should use an html parser to parse html.

Comment: Yeah I figured there are probably easier ways to do this. But I wanted to spend some time learning regex. Which parser would you recommend?

Comment: You could use DOMDocument if it is installed, it is part of php itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sub-pattern `stars_small_([0-9].[0-9])` to `stars_small_([0-9](?:\.[0-9])?)` as some of the urls only have one digit in the `SRC` attribute of the `IMG` tag.

Comment: @japanFour. The `?:` just makes the bracketed group non-capturing. The \ escapes the `.` so is interpreted as a literal `.` and not  the wildcard metacharacter. The `?` following the bracketed group makes it optional, i.e. there may optionally be a `.` and another digit.